# Laravel: seeding a nested set table with Faker

Tags: laravel, nested-sets, faker

I'm using Kalnoy/Nestedset and trying to seed my comments table using faker, but get "Array to string conversion" error.

The comment table looks like this:

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->nestedSet();
        });
```

The comment factory:

```
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(
    App\Models\Comment::class,
    function (Faker $faker) {
        return [
        'user_id' => function () {
            return factory('App\Models\User')->create()->id;
        },
        'post_id' => function () {
            return factory('App\Models\Post')->create()->id;
        },
        'body' => $faker->paragraph,
        ];
    }
);
```

And I can't really figure out what the seeder must look like. Here's my try:

```
public function run(Post $post)
    {
        $node = factory('App\Models\Comment'::class, 3)->create([

            'children' => [
                [
                    factory('App\Models\Comment'::class, 2)->create([
                        'post_id' => $post->id
                    ]),

                    'children' => [
                        [ factory('App\Models\Comment'::class, 1)->create([
                        'post_id' => $post->id
                            ]), 
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
    }

}
```

I also want to make sure that the post id of children as the same as parent's, but now it returns null.

Comment: In my experience "Array to string conversion" is usually something in the factory, and normally in the faker.  Some of the facker helper methods take a second argument that specify an array or string.  But I would have thought `paragraph` would have been ok as is.  Can't see any glaringly obvious errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keys of the array in the `create` method should be attributes that exist on your model. In your case `children` isn't an attribute on the `Comment` model.

Using the example from the [Using Factories](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database-testing#using-factories) documentation, you could rather create each comment and then use the `children()` relationship on the new models to create their children. For example:

```
public function run(Post $post)
{
    $node = factory('App\Models\Comment'::class, 3) // Create the root comments.
            ->create()
            ->each(function ($comment) use ($post) { // Add children to every root.
                $comment->children()->saveMany(factory(App\Comment::class, 2)->make([
                    'post_id' => $post->id
                ]))
                ->each(function ($comment)  use ($post) { // Add children to every child of every root.
                     $comment->children()->saveMany(factory(App\Comment::class, 2)->make([
                        'post_id' => $post->id
                    ]));
                });
            });
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! I wrapped this code in "factory('App\Models\Post'::class, 5)->create()->each(function($post){ "   to get the post id correctly and ran Post seeder instead.